# Dart simple function

Tags: dart, logic

Why does this code work:

```
addNumbers(num1, num2) {
print(num1 + num2);
}

void main() {
addNumbers(1, 2);
}
```

But this code doesn't work:

```
addNumbers(num1, num2) {
  num1 + num2;
}

void main() {
 int result = addNumbers(1, 2);
 print('$result');
}
```

How to make it work?

Sorry, I'm very new in programming and i don't know if it's possible.

Comment: You're just adding numbers, and not actually returning anything

Comment: I understand now.. Thank you very much!

Answer (score -2):

```
void main(){
    var list =["ashu","lakhan","ankit","arv","vijay"];
    print("Iterating the List Element");
    list.add('mohan');
    for(var a in list){  
        print('${list.indexOf(a)}=$a');
    }
}
```

Comment: Answers with only code (that's not even formatted) and no explanation at all are typically not useful at all.

Answer (score -2):

using await in async, look below for sample

```
void main() async{   

int result = await addNumbers(1, 2);
  print('$result');
 }
```